# Filter html table containing large data (More than 12K row)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I m working on small project that contains list of Website(Max added 12000 name),
I m asking user to select their interested for that i created piece of code like on js fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravi441988/E2Fq4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#title").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            $("#doc_list_content tbody>tr").hide();
            $("#doc_list_content td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();
        } else {
            $("#doc_list_content tbody>tr").show();
        }
    });
});
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "contains-ci": function (elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

Code is working fine with small amount of data, but when it is for 12000 row it cause browser not responding error.

I tried searching and played lot with my code. i want same type of functionality (on js fiddle) with js or php(littlebit knowledge of it)

My questions are:

1> Is it feasible to use this type of sorting?
2> any js/jquery solution?
3> I m aware of little bit of php as server side scripting, can it help to solve issue.

Thanks.

Comment: search data array, not DOM. WHere does table come from with 12K rows?

Comment: data is in mysql table, loading it when page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 don't use jquery for that... it's slow. use pure javascript

2 create an array containing the table

---

```
var tbl=[
 [a1,b1,c1,d1],
 [a2,b2,c2,d2],
]
```

---

3 use the `while--` loop as it's the fastest

```
var l=tbl.length
while(l--){
}
```

4 use very minimal shorthand or bitwise checks as they are faster.

```
var l=tbl.length
while(l--){
 !tbl[l][0]||(SOMETOGGLEFUNCTION(l))//l is the index of the real table 
}
```

this is the only way i know to check fast 12k records.

Answer (score 1):

if it were me I would basically use some sort of 'paging' to limit the users 'view' of the data to smaller chunks of data, but perhaps still allow for some sort of 'search' feature that searches / filters through ALL the data (not just the visible chunk) - through an array I guess.

in a past project I found that for speed / performance it was best to incrementally add objects to the DOM when the user had first scrolled down to the 'bottom' of the current chunk of data, then I would add a new chunk and remove the previous chunk... sort of how a user turns pages of a book depending on where they are in the book as opposed to laying all the individual pages of a book out in front of them on the floor -- maybe not the best analogy but hopefully you follow my thinking.  good luck.